# Dropdown action when selected

Tags: html, select, html-select

I am trying to make a HTML page list members of a list from a database, I have made the connections already but when using a dropdown to select the name of the list using an onclick, I would like it to display the list members below.  I have tried to incorporate an onclick function but it keeps linking to another page when I want it to still stay on the same page but list the members.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function changeFunc() 
{ 
var selectBox = document.getElementById("nameoflist"); 
var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value; 
alert(selectedValue); 
} </script>

<select name="nameoflist" onchange="changeFunc();">

<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Recipients</option>
<option value="All Recipients">All Recipients</option>
<option value="Tech List">TechList</option></select>
```

Look forward to your help!

CP

Comment: Show what you have tried. Maybe it's easier to help you fixing that.

Comment: What server language are you using, PHP? Where's that and the rest of your code?

Comment: Sorry have edited the above to include my code!

Comment: Just a quick note, you need to give the select element an id="nameoflist".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a couple lines, pass in `this` in your inline handler, and use that in your func:

```
function changeFunc(obj) 
{ 
    var selectedValue = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value; 
    alert(selectedValue); 
}

<select name="nameoflist" onchange="changeFunc(this);">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now how can I use this info to pull elements out of a database using Java?

Comment: @ChrisP -- Using an AJAX call